# User has no effective access when using setfacl -d

Tags: setfacl

I have a directory that I would like to share with two specific users. It has no contents yet, but I need all three of us to be able to add files and subdirectories, and it's important that all contents (by default at least) inherit the same permissions. The three of us get full access--nobody else gets anything.

I thought I'd accomplished this goal with:

```
setfacl -m u:myfriend:rwx Directory
setfacl -d -m u:myfriend:rwx Directory
```

But when I create a test file inside the directory, I see the following:

```
$$$ getfacl TESTFILE
# file: TESTFILE
# owner: me
# group: me
user::rw-
user:myfriend:rwx                     #effective:---
group::---
mask::---
other::---
```

I think the mask is the problem, but the mask on the directory doesn't match. This is what I get when I run getfacl on the Directory:

```
$$$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: me
# group: me
user::rwx
user:myfriend:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:myfriend:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the directory ACL were in that state when the file was created and that no `setfacl` or `chmod` calls have been made on that file? In other words: If you now execute `touch nonexisting_filename; getfacl nonexisting_filename` is the ACL output the same as in your question?

Comment: Nope, I get ```#effective:rw-```  on the new file. The TESTFILE was created after the ```setfacl``` commands, but it was created by copying a previously existing file. Do I need to worry about that when copying from elsewhere in the filesystem?

Comment: I do not know how this can happen. But I have encountered such cases several times recently.

Answer (score 0):

Something changes the ACL mask of the file after it was created. That is not supposed to happen. I cannot say how that may have happened but it is known to happen.

Any `setfacl` call on that file should correct that (unless `--no-mask` is given). You can set the mask explicitly, too:

```
setfacl -m m:rw filename
```